# Execute command after deploy AWS Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have problem with execute command after deploy, i have some node.js project and script, this script use some bin from node_modules, if i write my command for script in .ebextensions/.config he execute before npm install and return error (`"node_modules/.bin/some": No such file or directory`). How i can execute command after deploy. Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the following solution

I add to beanstalk config next command:

```
commands:
  create_post_dir:
    command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
    ignoreErrors: true
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/some_job.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      cd /var/app/current
      export PATH=$PATH:$(ls -td /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-* | head -1)/bin
      npm run some_script
```

This commands create(if not exist)  folder for post-hooks scripts and adds bash script. Scripts in this folders execute only after npm install, this very important for my problem.

Thanks to this guy http://junkheap.net/blog/2013/05/20/elastic-beanstalk-post-deployment-scripts/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had the same problem with PHP script. It worked like a charm.

Comment: Will this script run in case the deployment fails? @Strabek

Comment: @daxiang28: Use PATH=$PATH:`ls -td /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-* | head -1`/bin to add the node and npm executables to your path.

Answer (score 3):

create a file called `.ebextensions/post_actions.config`:

```
container_commands:
 <name of container_command>:
    command: "<command to run>"
```

this will be executed **after** the code was extracted, but before it was launched.

Comment: Thanks, but i need after it was launched(after deploy).

Comment: After the app is unzipped, it is first placed in a staging area before being copied into the designated app folder. For PHP, it's staged in `/var/app/ondeck` first.

1) `/var/app/current` is moved to `/var/app/current.old`
2) then `/var/app/ondeck` is moved to `/var/app/current`

If you need to perform any commands on the app folder, you can do so inside `post_actions.config` but target the changes against `/var/app/ondeck`. 

For each platforms' specific context of where the folders are being copied, you can look into the logs located at `/var/log/eb-activity.log`

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to go with the aws platform hooks. Where you can define the postdeploy hooks [AWS Patform Hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html)

In that inside the project root directory you can add .platform/hooks/postdeploy/

Insdie this path you can create xxx-postdeploy-script.sh. Files here run after the Elastic Beanstalk platform engine deploys the application and proxy server.This is the last deployment workflow step

Answer (score -3):

If you read the [AWS ebextensions documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html) they mention the execution, specifically where they mention that all commands are executed before the application version is deployed.

> "You can use the container_commands key to execute commands for your
>   container. The commands in container_commands are processed in
>   alphabetical order by name. They run after the application and web
>   server have been set up and the application version file has been
>   extracted, but before the application version is deployed."

If you deploy it for a second time it should work; this is because your application is already unpacked. This however is not a working solution because every new instance that is spawned will error.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Becouse EB create temporary folder which is trying to install app, if delpoy done EB move that to /var/app.... .