# How do I stop Elastic Beanstalk (apparently) removing my downloaded file?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have these container commands in an .ebextensions .config file:

```
container_commands:
  download_geography_data_01:
    command: "python scripts/download_geography_data.py"
  download_geography_data_02:
    command: "file /opt/python/current/app/data/geography/geography.sqlite"
```

And these execute perfectly when I use `eb create` - the second command is just there to put an entry in the log proving that the first script ran correctly and the file was created. I get a line like this in eb_activity.log, exactly as I would expect:

`Completed activity. Result: /opt/python/current/app/data/geography/geography.sqlite: SQLite 3.x database`

But 2 minutes later, it has my Python web server app is up and running and when it attempts to read that file, it fails:

`IOError: geography data file not found. Path searched was /opt/python/current/app/data/geography/geography.sqlite`

I then use `eb ssh` to log in to my environment, and it's right - the file is not there at all. It has seemingly disappeared between the configuration stage and the execution stage.

Anybody have any idea what could be going wrong? Could it somehow be clearing this file away?

I'm using the *"64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.4.3 running Python 2.7"* platform, if that is relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS Elastic Beanstalk have **never** removed your file, except for the app directory.

As AWS Documentation said in [Customizing Software on Linux Servers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands):

> You can use the `container_commands` key to execute commands for your container. The commands in `container_commands` are processed in alphabetical order by name. **They run after the application and web server have been set up** and the application version file has been extracted, but **before the application version is deployed**. They also have access to environment variables such as your AWS security credentials. Additionally, you can use `leader_only`. One instance is chosen to be the leader in an Auto Scaling group. If the `leader_only` value is set to `true`, the command runs only on the instance that is marked as the leader.

You put your SQLite database inside your app directory. When you update to a new one, your change into your old directory will be destroyed.

Before deploying:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-52-184 python]$ ll /opt/python/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  30 09:09 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul  30 09:12 bundle
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Jul  30 09:12 current -> /opt/python/bundle/3
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  30 09:09 etc
drwxrwxr-x 3 root wsgi 4096 Jul  30 09:10 log
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul  30 09:10 run
```

On deploying:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-52-184 python]$ ll /opt/python/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  30 09:09 bin
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul  30 09:18 bundle
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Jul  30 09:12 current -> /opt/python/bundle/3
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  30 09:09 etc
drwxrwxr-x 3 root wsgi 4096 Jul  30 09:10 log
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Jul  30 09:18 ondeck -> /opt/python/bundle/4
```

After deployed:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-52-184 python]$ ll /opt/python/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  30 09:09 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul  30 09:18 bundle
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Jul  30 09:18 current -> /opt/python/bundle/4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  30 09:09 etc
drwxrwxr-x 3 root wsgi 4096 Jul  30 09:10 log
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul  30 09:10 run
```

Do you notice your `/opt/python/current/app` changed? While on deploying, your `/opt/python/current/app` is pointed to `/opt/python/bundle/3`. And then after deployed, it is pointed to `/opt/python/bundle/4`. And then, the `/opt/python/bundle/3` (your old app) is removed.

So, the solution might be:

- Don't put your database inside your app directory. Just put anywhere outside your app directory.
- Run the command after deployed (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28866602/3427434)).

***UPDATE***: *First time deployment and first time update*

TLDR: If you create a new environment, the `/opt/python/current` was pointed to `/opt/python/bundle/1` and then it will be updated to `/opt/python/bundle/2`. So, before your app is deployed, there is a "default" app inside the instance.

I create a simple `.ebextensions` script to list all object inside `/opt/python`:

**.ebextensions/env-check.config**

```
files:
  "/opt/env-checker/env-checker.sh" :
    content : |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      TIMESTAMP=`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%N`
      if [ -d /opt/python ]
      then
        echo "PWD: $PWD" >> /opt/env-checker/${TIMESTAMP}_${1}
        ls -al /opt/python >> /opt/env-checker/${TIMESTAMP}_${1}
      else
        echo "PWD: $PWD" >> /opt/env-checker/${TIMESTAMP}_${1}
        ls -al /opt >> /opt/env-checker/${TIMESTAMP}_${1}
      fi
    mode : "000755"
    owner : root
    group : root
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/post-check.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      /opt/env-checker/env-checker.sh 02_post_deploy

commands:
  000_create_post_dir:
    command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
    ignoreErrors: true
  100_commands_envc:
    command: /opt/env-checker/env-checker.sh 00_commands

container_commands:
  101_container_commands_envc:
    command: /opt/env-checker/env-checker.sh 01_container_commands
```

In the first deployment (create a new environment using the above `.ebentensions`), I got this:

**20150730_141343_068692315_00_commands**:

```
PWD: /
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 bundle
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Jul 30 14:13 current -> /opt/python/bundle/1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 etc
drwxrwxr-x 3 root wsgi 4096 Jul 30 14:13 log
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 run
```

**20150730_141350_596104854_01_container_commands**

```
PWD: /opt/python/bundle/2/app
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 bin
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 bundle
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Jul 30 14:13 current -> /opt/python/bundle/1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 etc
drwxrwxr-x 3 root wsgi 4096 Jul 30 14:13 log
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Jul 30 14:13 ondeck -> /opt/python/bundle/2
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 run
```

**20150730_141355_731024404_02_post_deploy**

```
PWD: /
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 bundle
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Jul 30 14:13 current -> /opt/python/bundle/2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 etc
drwxrwxr-x 3 root wsgi 4096 Jul 30 14:13 log
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 run
```

In the second deployment (first update), I got this:

**20150730_141535_631911395_00_commands**

```
PWD: /
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 bundle
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Jul 30 14:13 current -> /opt/python/bundle/2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 etc
drwxrwxr-x 3 root wsgi 4096 Jul 30 14:13 log
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 run
```

**20150730_141542_258594223_01_container_commands**

```
PWD: /opt/python/bundle/3/app
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 bin
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:15 bundle
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Jul 30 14:13 current -> /opt/python/bundle/2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 etc
drwxrwxr-x 3 root wsgi 4096 Jul 30 14:13 log
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Jul 30 14:15 ondeck -> /opt/python/bundle/3
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 run
```

**20150730_141547_336930605_02_post_deploy**

```
PWD: /
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:15 bundle
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Jul 30 14:15 current -> /opt/python/bundle/3
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 etc
drwxrwxr-x 3 root wsgi 4096 Jul 30 14:13 log
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul 30 14:13 run
```

From the above result and some checking inside EC2 instance, I can conclude that:

- There is default app `/opt/python/bundle/1` directory before your app come into `/opt/python`.
- The `commands` in `.ebextensions` will be executed before your app file is in `/opt/python`.
- The working directory of `commands` is in `/`.
- The `container_commands` in `.ebextensions` will be executed after your app file is extracted in `/opt/python`.
- The working directory of `container_commands` is in your latest app directory in `/opt/python`.
- EB will remove your old app directory after the app is deployed.

I thought, another solution: you can put your SQLite database using current working directory of your script.

Comment: Please, read my whole question. I explained how I tested for the presence of the file and verified its existence.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you use Python environment (is it correct? you haven't mentioned which one is your [EB environment](docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html)) and put your database inside your app directory, but I already read your question a few times. Most of my Elastic Beanstalk work is in single docker environment and it doesn't have app directory in `/opt`.

Comment: But, basically, Elastic Beanstalk doens't touch anything outside its app and config directory.

Comment: "When you update to a new one" - what does that mean? I don't have old and new apps - I have no app at all yet. This happens when I create the environment for the first time. I can see how changing what `current` means could cause a problem but it's not clear what is happening since I can't ssh in to see what the structure is like before the container command is executed as it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: It looks like EB has default `/opt/python/current` be pointed to `/opt/python/bundle/1`. Your first app will be in `/opt/python/bundle/2`. That is why your database in `/opt/python/current` is removed. Check on my update.

Comment: For the *app* term in "When you update to a new one" is your *web app* (python app), not for *Elastic Beanstalk Application*.

Comment: I don't mind that the sqlite database disappears when I update my Python app, because I am saving it there each time I update the app. It's basically a read-only file. I guess I just need to find a new place to put it (and which is readable to the web server), but this is unfortunate as I wanted this file (and others I download) to be in the same location as some files I upload via Git.