# Django migrations with Docker on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a django app running inside a single docker container on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I cannot get it to run migrations properly, it always sees the old docker image and tries to run migrations from that (but it doesn’t have the latest files).

I package an `.ebextensions` directory with my EBS source bundle (a zip containing a Dockerrun.aws.json file and the .ebextensions dir). And it has a setup.config file that looks like this:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "CONTAINER=`docker ps -a --no-trunc | grep aws_beanstalk | cut -d' ' -f1 | head -1` && docker exec $CONTAINER python3 manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
```

Which is partially modeled after the comments on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540131/django-aws-elastic-beanstalk-migrate-database).

I have verified that it *can work* if I simply re-deploy the app a second time, since this time the previous running image will have the updated migrations file.

Does anyone know how to access the latest docker image or latest running container in an `.ebextensions` script?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on AWS Documentation on [Customizing Software on Linux Servers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands), `container_commands` will be executed before your app is deployed.

> You can use the `container_commands` key to execute commands for your container. The commands in `container_commands` are processed in alphabetical order by name. **They run after the application and web server have been set up** and the application version file has been extracted, but **before the application version is deployed**. They also have access to environment variables such as your AWS security credentials. Additionally, you can use `leader_only`. One instance is chosen to be the leader in an Auto Scaling group. If the `leader_only` value is set to `true`, the command runs only on the instance that is marked as the leader.

Take a look also into my answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31713040/3427434). It run some command in different app deployment state and give the command result.

So, your problem solution might be **create an post app deployment hook**.

***.ebextensions/00_post_migrate.config***

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/10_post_migrate.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      if [ -f /tmp/leader_only ]
      then
        rm /tmp/leader_only
        docker exec `docker ps --no-trunc -q | head -n 1` python3 manage.py migrate
      fi

container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "touch /tmp/leader_only"
    leader_only: true
```

Comment: Thanks—I’ll give it a try and report back. Do you also know if this will stop the deploy if the command returns a non-zero status?

Comment: I'm not sure. Need to try it first.

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to create an entrypoint script that runs migrations before starting django?

Comment: @elssar you mean in the Dockerfile itself? How could I get it to only run on `leader_only` then?

Comment: @EdwardSamuel just gave it a try and go it working! Thanks for the tips. I snooped around in the `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/` directory on an EB machine and took some other queues from the other scripts there, e.g., they source a `common.sh` file which exposes some functions that let you insert traces, warnings, or errors into the events process for a deploy. Seems to work great, only concern would be that it appears to not be officially documented nor sanctioned by AWS and Amazon could change everything around with no notice :O

Comment: @MrColes, fair point. Didn't think about the leader only part

Comment: Isn't it possble to run a seperate container before the real one in `container_commands`? Your container command will be something like: `docker run --rm $(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k <environment-name>_image) echo "Hello"`.

Will test this solution out right after I eat. I think it might be the best solution to this.

Comment: @EdwardSamuel this is nice, however how would you change this to cope with having an additional command running, say `collectstatic`? It will only run the first, as it will delete the `/tmp/leader_only` file on first post hook command.

Answer (score 3):

I am using another approach. What I did is run a container based on the newly build image, then pass in the environment variables from Elastic Beanstalk and run the custom command in that container. When that command is done, it will remove itself and proceed with the deployment.

So this is the script I have put inside `.ebextensions/scripts/container_command.sh` (make sure you replace everything that is within <>):

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMAND=$1

EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_IMAGE_STAGING=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k <environment_name>_image)
EB_SUPPORT_FILES=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k support_files_dir)

# build --env arguments for docker from env var settings
EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_ENV_ARGS=()

while read -r ENV_VAR; do
    EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_ENV_ARGS+=(--env "${ENV_VAR}")
done < <($EB_SUPPORT_FILES/generate_env)

docker run --name=shopblender_pre_deploy -d \
    "${EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_ENV_ARGS[@]}" \
    "${EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_IMAGE_STAGING}"

docker exec shopblender_pre_deploy ${COMMAND}

# clean up
docker stop shopblender_pre_deploy
docker rm shopblender_pre_deploy
```

Now, you can use this script to execute any custom command to the container that will be deployed later.

Something like this `.ebextensions/container_commands.config`:

```
container_commands:
    01-command:
        command: bash .ebextensions/scripts/container_command.sh "php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --no-interaction" &>> /var/log/database.log
        leader_only: true
    02-command:
        command: bash .ebextensions/scripts/container_command.sh "php app/console fos:elastica:reset --no-interaction" &>> /var/log/database.log
        leader_only: true
    03-command:
        command: bash .ebextensions/scripts/container_command.sh "php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --no-interaction" &>> /var/log/database.log
        leader_only: true
```

This way you also do not need to worry about what your latest started container is, which is a problem with the solution described above.