# elastic beanstalk node application within subdirectory

Tags: node.js, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How can I force elastic beanstalk nodejs application to look for the server application within a subdirectory server?

I'm building a modern SPA which has server and client application within one git project. Thus elastic beanstalk must not look for the server application within the root of the repository but within the subfolder ./server/. Client SPA is coded within ./client/ and build into an public folder within the server folder structure during build process. The fully build client version is checked in into git and must not be build while roleout.

So elastic beanstalk must npm install and npm run within the server sub directory.

Example folder structure:

```
~ git-root
|-- client
|    |-- ...
|
|-- server
|   |-- package.json
|   |-- src
|   |-- public
|   |-- (node_modules)
```

Comment: Have you found a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your desired package.json is within a subdirectory instead of the recommended root level location, you can add Buildfile and Profile files in your git root dir to respectively provide custom build and run commands to AWS Elastic Beanstalk:

```
~ git-root
|-- client
|    |-- ...
|
|-- server
|   |-- package.json
|   |-- src
|   |-- public
|   |-- (node_modules)
|
|--Buildfile
|--Procfile
```

**Buildfile**

```
install: cd server && npm install
```

**Procfile**

```
web: cd server && npm run
```

[AWS documentation for Buildfile & Procfile](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html)

Comment: I have tried this, Procfile commands run, but Buildfile commands do not run in nodejs env

Answer (score 1):

Elastic beanstalk is using some server configuration which can be changed. To change that configuration you can ssh to that machine or you can force proper configuration every application deployment.

The second approach is possible with adding custom code into `.ebextensions` folder placed in the root folder of your app.

More info about custom commands `.ebextensions` can be found i.e here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28608828/6541812
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.container.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

Comment: I do know of .ebextensions. However non of the provided links seems to solve the issue of running the server within an subdirectory. I do not like the idea of rewriting every functionallity and command which amazon is providing.

Answer (score 0):

I have a monorepository with NodeJS and Yarn, and I solved this problem this way:

- In the root, add a `package.json`, with the following entries:

```
...
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "cd ./$APP_FOLDER && yarn && yarn build",
    "start": "cd ./$APP_FOLDER && yarn start",
  },
```

**Ps:** In the subdirectory that contains the actual project, it must have it's own `package.json` as well

- In the Environment variables for the Elastic Beanstalk application (`configuration -> software -> Environment Properties`), add `APP_FOLDER` as an environment property with the folder name.
  [image]

**Ps**: I also had some issues building and running the application properly using `yarn`, so I added two `.ebextensions` to solve my problem:

- The first one was responsible to install `yarn` in the ElasticBeanstalk's machine:

> .ebextensions: 
> --- install_yarn.config 
> --- post_actions.config

For the file `install_yarn.config` (to install yarn in the machine):

```
commands:
  01_install_yarn:
    command: |
      set -e
      npm i -g yarn
      ln -s "$(npm bin --global)"/yarn /usr/bin/yarn
    test: "! yarn -v"
```

- I was using CodeBuild to build the code (run yarn build and transpile Typescript to Javascript), but when the built code reached ElasticBeanstalk, it came without `node_modules` properly installed. So I also added a [container_command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) to reinstall `node_modules` properly:

`post_actions.config`

```
container_commands:
    install_app_with_yarn:    
        command: "ls && yarn && cd ./$APP_FOLDER && yarn"
```

After doing this, I finally could see the beautiful green light from ElasticBeanstalk's health check:

[image]