# AWS SQS with Celery in Django

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, celery

I successfully hooked up Celery with Django and AWS SQS **locally**!! Now, I want to **deploy** my Django project. I need to **start my Celery worker** like this (which I usually do in Terminal locally):

```
celery -A my_project worker -l info
```

How can I do this when it is deployed? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Per OP, elastic beanstalk is being used so modified response

Create a new directory called `.ebextensions` in your codes root folder

Within that folder add a file `<your file name>.config` and ad the following contents

```
commands:
  create_post_dir:
    command: "mkdir -p /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
    ignoreErrors: true
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/start_celery.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      celery -A my_project worker -l info
```

NOTE: There could be more to this depending on what other configs, envs, or installations celery needs to start properly. But at least this should get you started.

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much for this response!! I am actually using Elastic Beanstalk. I thought this could work (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586837/execute-command-after-deploy-aws-beanstalk), but I don't really understand how to use it. Thanks!!

Comment: @NGI updated response with a bit more info on ebs that should hopefully help you get started.

Comment: @NGI I also just found this article as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/41161692/14167216 that provides scalability. But it goes into more detailed once you're ready to move into that front. But I would suggest play around with a simple script as the one provided and move into the more complex setup as you find it fitting.

Comment: Will do! Thanks so much for your help!